# An inquiry into Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis

*Note that this may be a very elementary proof using basic properties, still I am not sure about some part in its proof.

Let f be an analytic function on the punctured complex plane. Let N be an integer with $ N \ge 2 $ and consider $ f: A(\frac{1}{N},N) \to C$ , we wish to prove that we can decompose $f = f^{+} - f^{-} $ where $ f^{+}$ extends to a function analytic on D(N) and $f^{-}$ extends to a function analytic on $C - \bar D(\frac{1}{N})$ with $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f^{-}(z) = 0$

First of all, we have $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D(r2)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta -  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(r1)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta $ for any $z \in A(r1,r2)$

We first take a look at $f^{+}(z) =\int_{\partial D(r2)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta $, and try to expand it as a Taylor Series. Now, to apply Taylor Series we need to verify that $f^{+}(z)$ is analytic in D(r2), but this is in doubt since as r2 goes to $\frac{1}{N}$, $\zeta$ will necessarily touch on z and the whole function fail to be analytic. (Question 1)

For $f^{-}(z) =\int_{\partial D(r1)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta  $, we let $\zeta = \frac{1}{\zeta'} $ and $ w = \frac{1}{z}$, then $f^{-}(z) =\int_{\partial D(r1)} \frac{f(\frac{1}{w})}{\zeta' - w}\frac{w}{\zeta'} d\zeta  $, now how does it be analytic and admit a Taylor Series expansion? (Question 2)

Comment: Explain your notation ....what is $\;A\left(\frac1N,N\right)\;$ ...and what does it mean to get a Laurent series "such that we decompose..." ?? We can always decompose any function in an even and odd part, without any need of Laurent series, so what do you exactly mean here?

Comment: @DonAntonio I have corrected. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: The conclusion is somewhat more clear. But you say you want to _prove_ something. It's impossible to prove anything without making some assumption about something - you never say what the _hypothesis_ is!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have corrected again and added an assumption. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to know *a priori* that $f^+$ is analytic and hence has a Taylor series; we can use the integral to show directly that $f^+$ is given by a power series and deduce that it is analytic.

**Hint:** If $|z|<|\xi|$ then $$\frac1{\xi-z}=\frac1\xi\frac1{1-z/\xi}=\frac1\xi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z\xi\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi^{-n-1}z^n.$$

Now if you can show that the series converges uniformly on $C$, where $C$ is the curve you're integrating over, you get $$f^+(z)=\int_C \sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi^{-n-1}z^nf(\xi)\,d\xi=z^n\int_C \sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi^{-n-1}f(\xi)\,d\xi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n,$$where $$c_n=\int_C\xi^{-n-1}f(\xi)\,d\xi.$$

(Similarly for $f^-(z$, where $|\xi|<|z|$.)

Comment: Can I understand it in such way: if |z| is less than |ξ|, we can always gives a Taylor expansion? What confuses me is that we are trying to expand an integral here.

Comment: @Dinoman I added details at the end...

Comment: Impressive. Very straightforward and clear. Thanks for your effort. Can you explain more on the limit behavior？

Comment: @Dinoman I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Can you comment on $lim_{|z| \to ∞} f−(z)=0$ ?

Comment: The integral representation of $f^-$ shows that it vanishes at infinity. (the integrand tends to zero uniformly as $z\to\infty$).